# Does FBSDKLoginKit require a NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

The overall Facebook iOS [SDK docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) mention adding this description but doesn't specify for which part of the SDK it is required..